# ¿Como dejar seleccionado boton de una pantalla a otra?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Tengo un p-selectButton en la pantalla de login y otro en la pantalla de inicio para cambiar de idioma al loguearme. El idioma lo coge bien, pero lo que quiero es que dependiendo del idioma que cliquees en el login se quede seleccionado en la pantalla de inicio despues del logueo. Aqui esta mi codigo:

HTML

```
  <div class="language-menu">
            <p-selectButton (click)="onLanguageChange()" [options]="languages" [(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" optionLabel="name" selected="espanol.png">
                <ng-template let-item>
                    <img src="assets/images/{{item.value.flag}}" style="padding-top: 4px;"/>
                    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
                </ng-template>
            </p-selectButton>
        </div>
TS

this.languages = [
      {name: 'Spain', locale: 'es', flag: 'espanol.png'},
      {name: 'UK', locale: 'en', flag: 'ingles.png'},
    ];

 onLanguageChange() {
    this.locale = this.selectedLanguage.locale;
    if (this.locale == undefined || this.locale == null || this.locale.length == 0) {
      this.locale = "es";
    }
    // the lang to use, if the lang isn't available, it will use the current loader to get them
    this.translate.use(this.locale);
    this.sessionService.setItem("ng-prime-language", this.locale);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te seleccionan el idioma lo deberias guardar en algun sitio (localstorage por ejemplo). Cuando el usuario entre en el login, tu debes recoger ese valor y activar el  boton.

Ejemplo:

login.component.ts

```
login() {
    localStorage.setItem('language', this.selectedLanguage);
}
```

home.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language');
}
```